# what operation is needed to get the output using list input text and split string by space? answer are most appreciated

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

input:

```
name1 500

name2 200

name3 100

name4 400

name5 300
```

input: #second input

```
name1 100 name2

name2 50 name3

name3 25 name4

name5 100 name3

name4 75 name1
```

output:

```
name1 475

name2 250

name3 225

name4 350

name5 200
```

Comment: What is the logic behind  `name1 100 name2` becoming `name1 475`

Comment: name1 transfering 100 to name 2 and so on

Comment: So `500 transferring 100 to 250` becomes `name1 475`, that doesn’t help

Comment: name1 500 transferring 100 to name2 50 becomes name1 400 #line 1 input2
| name4 transferring 75 to name1 400 becomes name1 475 #line 5 input2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a dictionary with `.split()` and `int`, when you transfer take away from one dictionary item and add to the other.

```
lst = ['name1 500', 'name2 200', 'name3 100', 'name4 400', 'name5 300']

lst2 = ['name1 100 name2', 'name2 50 name3', 'name3 25 name4', 'name5 100 name3', 'name4 75 name1']

dct = {i.split()[0]: int(i.split()[1]) for i in lst}

for i in lst2:
    dct[i.split()[0]] -= int(i.split()[1])
    dct[i.split()[-1]] += int(i.split()[1])

print(dct)
# {'name1': 475, 'name2': 250, 'name3': 225, 'name4': 350, 'name5': 200}
```

Print line for line:

```
for i in dct:
    print(f'{i} {dct[i]}\n')
```

> ```
> name1 475
>
> name2 250
>
> name3 225
>
> name4 350
>
> name5 200
> ```